# Branch point at $\infty$- contours restricted?

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have a branch point at $z=a$ which is finite, this means I cannot take a contour around that point (hence we require a branch cut). If I have a branch cut at $z=\infty$ then what countours does this prevent me from using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A contour "near $\infty$" (e.g. a circle of radius $R$ centred at the origin, for sufficiently large $R$)